# Sync Git Repository on 2 remotes

Tags: git, gitlab

I have `Network A` and `Network B`.
`Stash` runs on `A` and `Gitlab` runs on `B` but they cannot communicate across networks.

1 group of developers actively work on `A` and the other group of developers actively work on `B`.
I have a machine that can see both.

So, daily I would like to be able to pull all updates, branches and tags from `A` and push to `B`, in reverse I would like to pull all updates, branches and tags from `B` and push to `A`.

I have cloned from `A` and added an additionl remote
`git remote add networkb git@<ip-address>:group/project.git`

So now I have `git remote -v`:

```
networkb git@<networkb-ip-address>:group/project.git (fetch)
networkb git@<networkb-ip-address>:group/project.git (push)
origin git@<networka-ip-address>:group/project.git (fetch)
origin git@<networka-ip-address>:group/project.git (push)
```

1. `git push networkb --all` only works for locally checked out branches.
2. `git push networkb '*:*'` pushed everything to `B` but I cannot see branches when checkout from
3. `git push networkb +refs/remtes/origin/*:refs/heads/*` worked for initial push but will result in a force push if run again.

Could anyone provide a sequence of steps to keeping these 2 remote repositories in sync?

Comment: How do you intend to resolve merge conflicts?

Comment: You can simply write a script shell that will update all your repos since you already have them as remotes.  `git fetch --all --prune` will update all your repositories

Comment: @merlin2011 i will have to resolve merge conflicts on my laptop I suppose when syncing.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your intermediate repository, you can the list of branch on origin using :

```
git for-each-ref --format="%(refname:short)" refs/remotes/origin
```

(change `origin` to `networkb` to get branches on networkb).

---

You can iterate through this list to either blindly push to networkb,
or try to first run a merge to see if any conflicts will happen,
or create `networka/branches` on `networkb` and and `networkb/branches` on `networka`.